# Opening SharePoint Excel file through desktop application warnings "Some files can contain viruses"

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, sharepoint

Only some users in my organization get this error when they try to open an excel file through excel desktop application that is one our SharePoint:

[image: see the warning message]

I tried every thing on the users excel options in the trust center but nothing helped. The problem is after the user opens the file which contains macros, it doesn't work the same as on my laptop that this error doesn't show. I think it somehow modifies the file if you continue opening the file. I know it is caused by some external links in the file, but assuming these links are necessary, how to fix this?
And also is there a way to replicate this error on my PC?

Comment: what is it modifying ?

Comment: Try to see if the following links can be adapted to your Office version: [link1](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/office365/troubleshoot/administration/enable-disable-hyperlink-warning) and [link2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/fe8f827f-a801-4fc0-b820-8dc30f816467/unable-to-hyperlink-to-company-applications-office-2016-proplus?forum=Office2016ITPro).

Comment: @PeterH by modifying, I mean Excel (the desktop application) may block or delete the content that causes this warning.

Comment: @harrymc I will try that and will update you with the result. Thanks.